# Why is XCode ignoring my Deployment Target?

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

I have an iPad running iOS 7.0.4 connected to my machine.  I am attempting to deploy an Ionic (Cordova) project to the device.

My Deployment Target is set to 7.0:

[image]

However, I continue getting the "deployment target" error message:

[image: X's iPad runs iOS 7.0.4, which is lower than Y's minimum deployment target. Change your project's minimum deployment target or upgrade X's iPad's version of iOS.]

How can I get XCode to successfully deploy to my iPad?

Comment: Are you using the Xcode 8 beta?

Comment: I am running Version 6.3.2 (6D2105).

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not on the latest Xcode version?

Comment: I haven't taken the time to update my OS X - I'm still on 10.10.4 Yosemite.  In order to update my Xcode, I need to update OS X, right?  Either way, iOS 7 is pretty old (but not ancient old); shouldn't iOS 7.0.4 still be supported pretty well in Xcode 6?

Comment: Only 3% of users are using a version lower than iOS 8, see https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/ Xcode 8 removes support for iOS 7 Deployment Targets. So maybe you don't have to worry about iOS 7 support that much anymore. But you are right: Xcode 6 should definitely still support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  Cordova version 4.0.0+, upon which Ionic depends, requires iOS 8.0+.  It is hard-coded into the `platforms/ios/cordova/build.xcconfig` file:

```
IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 8.0
```

This hard-coded value was overriding any changes I made in the Xcode GUI.  I was able to get my project to deploy on my device by changing `8.0` to `7.0` in `build.xcconfig`.

For others who are also using Ionic/Cordova, I suppose the solution is disappointing but simple: **only target iOS 8.0 and up**.

References:

- [Cordova Announcement](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/12/08/cordova-ios-4.0.0.html)
- [JIRA Issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9726)